# Angularjs Dynamically load all images before displaying them all at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I am implementing a image stacking that comes from multiple images that are being loaded from multiple locations i.e local media folder and some from another server. I want these images to be displayed all at once after being loaded especially when changing angle for the images. See example [here](http://studentmossaonline.com/designa-studentmossa)

I am developing with angularjs v1.4.4. And currently I am using a promise that pre_loads image as seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQHrI.png).
What I want is to avoid lagging that happens when I am changing an angle that is caused due to dynamically loading images of different sizes and displaying them before they are fully loaded or takes longer to load.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please post your relevant code here in your post

Comment: it looks like you are overdoing it, on your html you should have a list of images and control their visibility through angular. If you really need to access the DOM you should always do it using directives.